# Python find ONLY the first instance of a word in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop

Newbie to Python here.
I would like to extract the sentence where the first instance of the words in the list have been found. Currently, it is extracting all strings which have the word 'dog' and 'cat'. I tried `(i.split('.')[0])` but this is not working either. Can anyone help please?

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. the dog want want want was there. '

lst=[]
words=['dog', 'cat', 'chocolate']
for i in text.split('.'):
    for j in words:
        if j in i:
            print(i.split('.')[0])
            lst.append (i.split('.')[0]) 
else:
    lst.append('na')
    print('na')
```

Output:

```
the dog was there

the cat is there too

the dog want want want was there

na
```

Desired output:

```
the dog was there

the cat is there too

n/a (because choclate is not found)
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making a lot of changes to your code, your output can be achieved by using 'remove' on your 'words' list.

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. the dog want want want was there. '

lst=[]
words=['dog', 'cat', 'chocolate']
for i in text.split('.'):
    for j in words:
        if j in i:
            print(i.split('.')[0])
            words.remove(j) # this will remove the matched element from your search list
            lst.append (i.split('.')[0]) 
else:
    lst.append('na')
    print('na')
```

Comment: thank you! it does change the order of the items in the list, is it possible to keep the order?

Comment: You can create a copy of the word list and work with it. This is in anyway advisable because `remove` alters your original list. If all the words have been found once, your list will be empty at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you reverse your loops, you can just use `break` to go to the next word:

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. the dog want want want was there. '

lst=[]
words=['dog', 'cat', 'chocolate']
for j in words: # each word
    for i in text.split('.'):  # each sentence
        if j in i:
            print(i.split('.')[0])
            lst.append (i.split('.')[0]) 
            break  # next word
else:
    lst.append('na')
    print('na')
```

Output:

```
the dog was there
 the cat is there too
na
```

Comment: Reversing the loops is also good because the same sentence _might_ be the first one to contain two different words -- you want to be able to return it again, and this will do it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be keeping track of which words you have found. This could be done like this, if you are fine with modifying the `words` list:

```
text= 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. the dog want want want was there. '

lst=[]
words=['dog', 'cat', 'chocolate']
for sentence in text.split('.'):
    sentence = sentence.strip()  # Remove whitespace around sentence
    for word in words:
        if word in sentence:
            print(sentence)
            lst.append(sentence) 
            # Remove the found word from words
            words.remove(word)
else:
    lst.append('na')
    print('na')
```

I also changed some variable names in order to make the code more easily readable.
This piece of code outputs the following

```
the dog was there
the cat is there too
na
```

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking your code down (just one for loop), you can use `pop()` on the word list to remove an item from there:

```
text = 'the dog was there. the cat is there too. python is the best. the dog want want want was there. '
sentences = text.split('.')
words=['dog', 'cat', 'chocolate']

for sentence in sentences:
    # Takes the first word as long as there are items in the list!
    word = words.pop(0) if words else None
    if word and word in sentence:
        print(sentence.strip())  # Removes whitespaces arround the sentence 
else:
    print('na')
```

Output:

```
the dog was there
the cat is there too
na
```